# ADF testing and ARDL model cointegration

Tags: time-series, cointegration, augmented-dickey-fuller, ardl

i am studying the impact of trade openness on manufacturing growth from 1967 to 2013 in Tunisia. My variables are Manufacturing value added(MVA), openness(OPEN), GFCF and manufacturing labor force (MLAB)
1/ MVA (lag1) and MLAB (lag4) are I (0) no constant , no trend
MVA, OPEN and GFCF are stationary at first difference and satisfy the 3 equations of ADF test, but MLAB at first difference is only stationary when I include constant and trend. can I claim that MLAB is stationary at first difference (I mean is not I (2))?

Can I run ARDL model in this case?

2/I include trend and intercept in my ARDL model but their coefficients are not significant, what should I do?

Can I delete them and estimate again my model? In this case what critical value I should consider for my ARDL model? Unrestricted intercept and unrestricted trend //or no intercept and no trend because their coefficient are not significant. What is best software I can use?

Answer (score 1):

1/ MLAB is stationnary at first difference, so according to sattionnarity'order of the others variables, you can model ARDL.

2/ There are 5 cases of ARDL'specification. To compute and take a decision on the existence of a long run relationship, you have to compare the F-stat to the critical values established by Pesarn, Shin and Smith.
Check here http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/jae.616/pdf